# name of the grammatical structure

Tags: grammar

Please help with this:

**Name of the grammatical structure:

must have been.......**

This is the question i've been given and I'm finding it difficult to find the answer.

I've been instructed not to worry about the rest of the sentence.

But the rest of the sentence is : It must have been so frightening for Malak to see her mum so ill.

Comment: This is a sequence of three auxiliary verbs. Probably your teacher beiieves there is a special name for it, and that learning that name will teach you how to use this sequence. Maybe something with a number in it. Native English speakers never learn these things, and I wonder why non-native teachers feel so strongly about knowing names, especially since they are never standard linguistic names; they're always peculiar to one region.

Comment: @JohnLawler Couldn't we use a simple descriptive term such as "a modal construction of the verb 'to be'"(in which the names are universally known and used)?

Comment: That basically means "a sequence of three auxiliary verbs, of which one is a modal and another is _be_". Why not just list the three verbs? It's more accurate and shorter.

Comment: It's a perfect tense verb phrase in a 'catenative' construction. Auxiliary verbs like the "must" and "have" in your example are just as much catenative verbs as some of the lexical ones are. Both kinds take subordinate non-finite clauses as complement. In "It must have been so frightening", "have been so frightening" is a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "must". Within that clause is the further subordinate clause "been frightening" functioning as complement of "been".

Comment: Tell *that* to the teacher!!

Comment: @Hazra “A perfect tense verb phrase” may be enough for the teacher.

Comment: "Modal plus past infinitive."

Comment: @Greybeard, Could 'infinitive' be past? Just a doubt. Or, are you referring to usages like to do/ to be doing/ to have done/ to have been done...to must do/ must be doing/ must have done/ must have been doing?

Comment: @RamPillai 1. The verb form that follows a modal is a bare infinitive. *"He must/will/might, etc **go** home."* Thus we can have *"He must/will/might, etc **have gone** home."* **2** *to must do"* (which is expressed as "to have had to do") and *must to do"* are not possible.

Comment: @Greybeard; Yeah. You are right

Comment: @JohnLawler, they are not all auxiliaries because *be* is the main verb here.

Comment: In English, _be_ is always an auxiliary, because it always behaves like an auxiliary -- it inverts, it contracts, it deletes, it participates in multiple constructions and idioms. One of its jobs is to be the auxiliary verb for predicate nouns and adjectives, which some people think makes it a "main verb" in those constructions because the main predicate isn't a verb.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it has a specific name.
But usually I refer to this topic as "Modals of deduction"(usually about present or future).

Exactly for your example it's "modals of deduction in the past".

When we say, **"You must have been tired"**(Because you worked hard that day), this is just our guess about the most possible past event or condition.

Comment: "Modals of deduction" is about right for epistemic modals. I spose "Modals of authority" would refer to deontic modals.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose we say,

She will sing./ She will be singing./ She will have sung./ She will have been singing.

Now, trying setting your example in this mold:

It must frighten.../It must be frightening. / It must have frightened./ It must have been frightening.